# Convert date time into universal timestamp in PHP for calendars

Tags: php

I am building a PHP service that will allow people to click on an `Add to calendar` button on their mobile devices.

How do I convert `2009-09-12 15:00` into the example timestamp I have been given `20091109T101015Z` using PHP?

I have played around with `strtotime` `gmdate` but I think I am just missing the correct format parameter.

Thanks

Comment: WTF? How does "2009-09-12 15:00" map to "20091109T101015Z". Assuming that order of month and date are transposed, this implies that there is a timezone transition involved when there is no timezone data supplied. How do you get 6 digits of precision in the time part from 4 digits in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = '2009-09-12 15:00';
$formatted_date = gmdate('Ydm\THis\Z', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use formating?

```
$date = new DateTime("2009-09-12 15:00");
$formated = $date->format("Ydm\THis\Z");
```

For reading: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 $the_date = strtotime("2010-01-19 00:00:00");
 echo(date_default_timezone_set("UTC") . "<br />");
 echo(date("YmdTG:iz", $the_date) . "<br />");
```